# DocuSign Service Integration Oauth and API 2.1 timelines

Tags: docusignapi

I have some rough Idea but want to know timelines regarding End of Life plan for below in Production Environments. So that I can plan my development plan accordingly well.

1. For new/Existing Customers till when API 2.0 will be valid and after which date we must use API 2.0?
2. For new/Existing Customers till when basic authentication will be valid and after which date we must JWT base OAUTh2 authentication?

Kindly help me with all this information as I need to plan my integration changes accoridngly.

Answer (score 0):

Beginning Feb 2022, esig rest API will enter maintenance mode. It will still work but will receive few updates after that. [Blog post](https://www.docusign.com/blog/developers/recipient-connect)

All rest API clients must update to an oauth V2 flow by September 2022. See the [blog post](https://www.docusign.com/blog/developers/september-2022-oauth2-required)